# What does CentOS 6.5 netinstall text version actually install?

Tags: centos, installation, centos6.5, netinstall

I just performed a install of Centos 6.5 by utilizing the netinstall. When choosing the text installer I understand that it doesn't give you custom partitioning options or allow you to customize your install.

However, is there a listing to figure out exactly what it installs? I am looking for a bare minimum install with no GUI, Apache, PHP, or MySQL. I can verify the apache/mysql does not have a service installed. Could not find any information about how minimal the install was though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text-based CentOS installer installs only the "minimal" installation set, about 214 packages the last time I counted. Or maybe it was 241. Anyway, a very small set that is identical to what you would get if you chose "minimal" in the GUI installer.

The [Installation Guide has this to say](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-pkgselection-x86.html):

> If you install Red Hat Enterprise Linux in text mode, you cannot make package selections. The installer automatically selects packages only from the base and core groups. These packages are sufficient to ensure that the system is operational at the end of the installation process, ready to install updates and new packages.

Answer (score 4):

The installer will leave an anaconda generated kickstart file in root's home that contains the specific install options - most of the info needed to rebuild the box with only a few text edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can see installed packages with this command:

```
$ rpm -qa | less
```

The netinstall installs a minimal set of packages that RedHat/CentOS considers essential.